# Datatable : result not show after cause by one column

Tags: php, datatable

My datatable just show "Processing" not the result. It's happened after I try to show another result from a column from my DB. First time I'm just show 8 column (include hidden ID column).
But, After I add 1 column it become:
[image]
I got this after add `Detail` column.
whether, if the data appears the table become wider so it show like this? Nothing error at query and firebug not show error.

```
if($ssWhere!="") {
                $sQuery = "SELECT prob_id,Model,Serial,Lotno,Date,Symptom,Cause,Status,CM,`Detail` FROM OQC ".$ssWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
                 } else {
                        $sQuery = "SELECT prob_id,Model,Serial,Lotno,Date,Symptom,Cause,Status,CM,`Detail` FROM OQC ".$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit;
                        }
        $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // subm$

        $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
        $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() $
        $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
        $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

        $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(prob_id) FROM OQC";

        $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  //$
        $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
        $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

//echo "sEcho is ".$_POST['sEcho'];

        $sOutput = '{';
        $sOutput .= '"sEcho": '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).',';     //   '.intval($_POST['sEcho']).', ';
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalRecords": '.$iTotal.', ';
//      $sOutput .= '"iTotalDisplayRecords": '.$iFilteredTotal.', \';
        $sOutput .= '"iTotalDisplayRecords": '.$iTotal.', ';
        $sOutput .= '"aaData": [ ';
        while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
        {
                $sOutput .= "[";
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['prob_id']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Model']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Serial']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Lotno']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Date']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Symptom']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Cause']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Status']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['CM']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Detail']).'"';
                $sOutput .= "],";
        }
        $sOutput = substr_replace( $sOutput, "", -1 );
        $sOutput .= '] }';

        echo $sOutput;
```

if not show the `Detail` all can work normally.Why?

---

at firebug show :
[Result](http://pastebin.com/PYwwCT8T)

Comment: I hate with this trouble, better I choose jqgrid.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to mention the column name in jquery datatable script.